# How to download & install Bonjour Services on a Windows 7 64 bit computer?

Tags: install, windows, bonjour

The Bonjour Service was causing error messages in my event log (Windows 7 laptop).  I have deleted it and the Bonjour Print Service.

I now need to re-install it.  Where do I download it and how do I install it on a Windows 7 (64 bit) laptop?

Answer (score 3):

You can download Bonjour for Windows from Apple's [Bonjour support pages](https://www.apple.com/support/bonjour/).

Bonjour for Windows is bundled with [Bonjour Print Services for Windows](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL999):

> Bonjour Print Services for Windows lets you discover and configure Bonjour-enabled printers from your Windows computer using the Bonjour Printer Wizard.